# Zing Charts transform epoch dates to human readable

Tags: javascript, zingchart

I'm trying to use the transform:date from zingcharts scale objects http://www.zingchart.com/docs/json-attributes-syntax/scale-objects/transform/ to display an epoch date in the x-scale.

Some of the epoch dates I'm using are: 1402444800,1402531200,1402617600.

Using their Epoch Converter link the results I should be seeing are: 11 Jun 2014, 12 Jun 2014,13 Jun 2014.

Instead I get: 17 Jan 1970,17 Jan 1970,17 Jan 1970.
Working code is http://jsfiddle.net/Rodmunera/j1ddL5k6/5/

```
  "scale-x": {
    "transform": {
      "item": {
        "visible": false
      },
      "guide": {
        "visible": false
      },
      "all": " %d %M %Y",
      "type": "date"
    },
    "decimals": 0,
    "format": "%v",
    "mirrored": 0,
    "text": "Shows",
    "values": [
      1402444800,
      1402531200,
      1402617600
    ]
  },
```

I'm pretty sure I'm implementing this feature properly, can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? or if feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rodmunera,

You just have to add three more 0's to each of your Unix times, as ZingChart uses milliseconds, not seconds.

I've updated your demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nmastracchio/ctcpcc0p/1/).

```
"values": [
      1402444800000,
      1402531200000,
      1402617600000
    ]
```

I'm a member of the ZingChart team, so if you have any more questions, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Thank you! I've been banging my head against this for a while now! Works perfectly :)

Comment: Any idea why the values on the Y axis are out of frame? http://jsfiddle.net/Rodmunera/j1ddL5k6/7/